# Call dynamic method in c#

Tags: c#, json, string, wcf

I have json request parameters

```
{
  "exp": 0,
  "iat": 0,
  "method": "Login",
  "apiSecretKey": "y109m113e122",
  "userName": "test@test.com",
  "password": "test",
  "isGuestCustomerId": 1
}
```

and Method is in WCF rest api service(C#)

```
Login(string apiSecretKey, string userName, string password, int isGuestCustomerId)
```

How will I pass these request parameter to Login Method?

Note : I have around 200 methods to call in this way with different parameters like

```
Register(string apiSecretKey, string emailId, string password, string firstName, string lastName, string phoneNumber, string gender, string dateOfBirth, string companyName)
and so on different methods
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173183.aspx), lots of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Json.Net,

```
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
object instance = .... ; //Instance of your class containing methods..

var mi = instance.GetType().GetMethod(jobj["method"].ToString(), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var parameters = mi.GetParameters()
                 .Select(p => Convert.ChangeType(jobj[p.Name].ToString(), p.ParameterType))
                 .ToArray();

object retval = mi.Invoke(instance, parameters);
```

Comment: Can you please advise why I am getting error when I pass 2nd request Parameters to InfoEdit using your way to call different method.Please refer Updated question. I am  getting error "Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'DataClass.InfoEditResponse'. " and If I remove .ToString from the code " jobj[p.Name].ToString(), p.ParameterType " then I got error "Object must implement IConvertible."

Comment: @Hrdk Please don't edit your question after 2 months to ask new question. Instead, ask a new question with exact definition of your problem. I rolled back your edit...